# how to add Linear Gradient color on borderColor in expo react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, colors, expo, gradient

*add Linear Gradient color on border*
i want to know how to use in stylesheet  a linear gradient.

```
 borderColor:['color1',color2]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In order to add linear Gradient first run `expo add expo-linear-gradient`

Then in order to add horizontal gradient

```
 <LinearGradient
            start={[0, 1]}
            end={[1, 0]}
            colors={[color1, color2]}
          />
```

For vertical gradient

```
 <LinearGradient
            start={[0, 0]}
            end={[0, 1]}
            colors={[color1, color2]}
          />
```

Answer (score 1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVYkK.png)
please check output image

Let’s start by creating a new button:

```
<TouchableOpacity 
onPress={() => {})}
style={styles.buttonContainer}>
<Text style={style.buttonText}>Login</Text>
```

Styles:

```
 buttonContainer: {
    width: 200,
    alignItems: 'center',
},
buttonText: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#4C64FF',
    padding: 15,
    width: 200
}
```

Start by installing the react-native-linear-gradient package

```
<LinearGradient
      colors={['#00FFFF', '#17C8FF', '#329BFF', '#4C64FF', '#6536FF', '#8000FF']}
      start={{x: 0.0, y: 1.0}} end={{x: 1.0, y: 1.0}}
      style={{ height: 48, width: 200, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', width: 200}}
    >
```

for more info : https://codeburst.io/linear-gradient-for-border-color-in-react-native-5bcab3eea1c9

Comment: I want the gradient color on the border